# How to add text field auto suggestions in a drop down list?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I have one Billing Address page in the app. I have to remember all text field data adds by the user and show them in a drop down list.

I have to create a table view on the bottom of the text fields. I am also using `IQKeyboardManager` for maintaining text fields when the keyboard appears.

So, when the keyboard appears, the table view is overlapping on the back of keyboard. How to resolve this issue?

I am also attaching the screenshot:

[image: IQKeyboardManager toolbar in front of text field]

Comment: as this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/177 you can hide toolbar of keyboard

Comment: but I have not hide the toolbar.

Comment: i think you want to move textfield more up side right? then use some other way to maintain keyboard avoide

Comment: yes use some other way to maintain keyboard avoide

Comment: check my answer that must be help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i doing some search i found `keyboardDistanceFromTextField` property of `IQKeyboardmanager` class. You can set disctance of keyboard for the specific textField object using following code:

```
YourDropDowntextFiled.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 250;
```

So make use of this line of code for your textfiled and you can easily show the drop-down list visible.

I have checked in Demo look like following. One i did not add `keyboardDistanceFromTextField` so it just appear after keyboard and other i apply propery so it will show big distance from the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look This. You can use RxSwift for compact coding

```
var autoCompleteTableView: UITableView = UITableView()
let containerView: UIView = UIView()
var placesArray = Observable.just([String]())

func createAutocompleteContainer() {

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let width : CGFloat = screenSize.width-138
        let height : CGFloat = 200
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 62, width: width, height: height)
        autoCompleteTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.size.width, height: containerView.frame.size.height)
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        placesArray
            .bindTo(autoCompleteTableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
                cell.textLabel?.text = "\(element)"
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(hex: "#b2b2b2")
                cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)


        autoCompleteTableView
            .rx_modelSelected(String)
            .subscribeNext { value in
                self.textField = value
                self.containerView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        self.containerView.addSubview(autoCompleteTableView)
        self.view.addSubview(containerView)

    }
```

Comment: var placesArray = Observable.just([String]()) what is Observable

Comment: Observable var for RxSwift Binding  placesArray.bindTo ... Or you can write var placesArray = Variable([])

and bind like this
placesArray.asObservable().bindTo ...